Extract the closest two numbers that multiply to create a given number
I made a CPU based raytracer in PyGame which uses a tile per thread to render each section of the screen. Currently I divide the screen vertically between lines, this doesn't give me the best distribution: I want to divide threads in even boxes covering both the X and Y directions. For example: If my resolution is x = 640, y = 320 and I have 4 threads, I want a list of 4 boxes representing tile boundaries in the form (x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max), in this case the result being [(0, 0, 320, 160), (320, 0, 640, 160), (0, 160, 320, 320), (320, 160, 640, 320)].
Problem is I don't see how to automatically divide the number of threads into a 2D grid: I want to extract the closest two whole numbers that multiply to match the thread setting. If this number can't be divided evenly, jump to the closest one that can... for instance no two integers can multiply to create 7, use 6 or 8 instead. I tried math.sqrt but it only works for perfectly divisible numbers like 16, even when rounding that it won't give accurate results for values like 32. What is the simplest solution?
Examples: 4 = 2 * 2, 6 = 2 * 3, 8 = 2 * 4, 9 = 3 * 3, 16 = 4 * 4, 24 = 4 * 6, 32 = 4 * 8, 64 = 8 * 8.

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the following:
Given a number x > 0, find the pair of factors (z, h) where the absolute difference of (z, h) is the at a minimum.
x is the number of available threads and (z, h) will then be the number of tilings you will have (vertically, horizontally).
If the number of pixels doesn't divide perfectly in your number of tilings, you can add the remainder to the last tiling.
The most efficient algorithm that I can think of is as follows:

start with x, the number we want to factor.
calculate sqrt(x) and round it down to the nearest integer. Call this s.
the smaller factor we're looking for will be the largest divisor of x that's less than or equal to s.

In python code it'll look something like this:
import math

def closest_factors(x):
    s = int(math.sqrt(x))
    
    for z in range(s, 0, -1):
        if x % z == 0:
            return z, x // z

x = 60
factor1, factor2 = closest_factors(x)
print(f"The factors of {x} with the least difference are: {factor1} and {factor2}")
print(f"Their difference is: {abs(factor1 - factor2)}")

There may be a mathematical formula for this that speeds it up, but I'm not familiar with it.
Updated according to @MirceaKitsune 's suggestion in the comments.

Thank you, works perfectly and just as intended! I like how if the number isn't divisible it will still give you x = 1, y = num without changing the count, which ensures the number doesn't need to be modified and anything will ultimately work.

Noticed the def f(y): return x // y - y check doesn't seem to be needed: Everything seems to work perfectly even without that. Is there a reason for it that I missed? Just figured I'd double check to be extra safe.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method for the mathematical trick that can speed this up. Though with numbers in the tens of thousands, O(sqrt(x)) is just fine.

@MirceaKitsune you are right, there is no need for that part since the number will never become negative (at the latest, any number divided by one minus one will be zero and the second conditional will also be true). I didn't look through the code properly. Will update!

You would first need to find the divisors of nThreads with something like:
divisors = [i for i in range(2,floor(nThreads/2)+1) if nThreads%i==0]

You end up with a list with increasing numbers (I am no Python developper, but that souldn't be an issue for you).
If its length is greater than 2:

if it's odd, you pick the central value as in 16 -> [2,4,8] : you end up with 16=4*4.
if it's even, you pick the two central values as in 24 -> [2,3,4,6,8,12] : you end up with 24=4*6.

else you choose a smaller number of thread.
The complete code could be something like this:
from math import *

nThreads=16;

divisors = [i for i in range(2,floor(nThreads/2)+1) if nThreads%i==0]

print(divisors)

if len(divisors)%2 ==1 : # if odd
    keptValues = [divisors[floor(len(divisors)/2)], divisors[floor(len(divisors)/2)]]
else: # if even
    keptValues = [divisors[floor(len(divisors)/2)-1], divisors[floor(len(divisors)/2)]]

print(keptValues)

NOTE: Again, the code may not be following Python Best Practices, so feel free to edit :)

To check all numbers if they are divisors is quite expensive for not small numbers.

Well, it's correct, but that can be performed once at the beginning and stored. And nobody said anything regarding performance :)

Thanks, can confirm this works as intended. Indeed performance isn't an issue as this segment only needs to run once at startup, thankfully I don't need to execute it per frame.

My final function adapted from user1984's solution, reduced to a few lines for simplicity: Tested with multiple values and it always works as intended. As a bonus if unit isn't divisible it will return unit, 1 so the grid will work no matter what the count is.
def grid(unit: int):
    for i in range(math.isqrt(unit), 0, -1):
        if not unit % i:
            return unit // i, i


You could use math.isqrt(unit) instead of math.trunc(math.sqrt(unit))

Thanks for mentioning that part, edited and fixed it in my code.
